# My GridView in my fragment is not visible

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I am making an Activity with 2 fragments in it to display 2 different functionalities. The problem I am having is that there is a grid view in my first fragment that is not visible. The application runs without crashing, I just have no idea why the GridView is not visible.

Here is the fragment in question:

```
public class PaletteFragment extends Fragment {

GridView grid;
TextView label;

public PaletteFragment() {

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View palette =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_palette, container, false);

    label = palette.findViewById(R.id.label);
    label.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.labelText));

    grid = palette.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    grid.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(palette.getContext()));

    return palette;
}
```

}

And here is the XML for the fragment:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="317dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
    tools:visibility="invisible" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="119dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/labelText"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/gridView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

If it helps, here is the adapter I used on the GridView:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
ArrayList<Integer> colorVal = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public CustomAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return colorVal.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View View, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    String[] colorName = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.colorName);

    colorVal.add(Color.RED);
    colorVal.add(Color.BLUE);
    colorVal.add(Color.BLACK);
    colorVal.add(Color.GREEN);
    colorVal.add(Color.WHITE);
    colorVal.add(Color.LTGRAY);
    colorVal.add(Color.DKGRAY);
    colorVal.add(Color.MAGENTA);
    colorVal.add(Color.YELLOW);
    colorVal.add(Color.CYAN);

    TextView text = new TextView(context);
    text.setText(colorName[i]);
    text.setBackgroundColor(colorVal.get(i));
    text.setTextSize(22);
    text.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);

    if(text.getText().toString().equals(context.getResources().getString(R.string.black))){
        text.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    }

    return text;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

When you call your adapter, your colorVal list is empty and hence getCount always return 0. That is why your getView fun is not getting called.

Just move your code to update the colorVal list to the constructor and you are good to go!

```
public CustomAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;

    colorVal.add(Color.RED);
    colorVal.add(Color.BLUE);
    colorVal.add(Color.BLACK);
    colorVal.add(Color.GREEN);
    colorVal.add(Color.WHITE);
    colorVal.add(Color.LTGRAY);
    colorVal.add(Color.DKGRAY);
    colorVal.add(Color.MAGENTA);
    colorVal.add(Color.YELLOW);
    colorVal.add(Color.CYAN);
}
```

You can also create this list in the fragment and send it in the adapter's constructor.